# Why relational operator not working in pointers and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why `while(p != p+sz)` is an error in the following code :-

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int sz= (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
  int *p = arr, *l = &arr[sz];

  while(p != p+sz){
    *p = 0;
    p++;
  }

  for(auto i: arr){
    cout<<i<<endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

However, If I changed while condition to `while(p != l)`, It's going to work but why I am not able to use relational operator( `while(p < p+sz)` or adding integral value to pointer(`while(p != p+sz`)?

It output as : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: When `sz` is not 0, when does the expression `p != p+sz` will ever be false? Try to come up with some values for `p` and `sz` that produces a false result.

Comment: Are you asking why x can't equal x+y for nonzero y?

Comment: In the `while` loop condition, instead of `p != p+sz`, try `p != arr+sz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never reach `p + x` be incrementing the `p` itself, it will always be exactly `x` steps from `p`. You loop puts the pointer out of its bounds and then dereferences it.

You should pre-compute the value using `p` and then use it:

```
// ...
auto limit = p+sz; // Pre-compute the limit
while (p != limit){
    *p = 0;
    p++;
} // ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you explain very well with a better solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why relational operator not working with integers?

Simpler example, same effect:

```
int main(){
  int sz= 5;
  int p = 0;

  while(p != p+sz){
    p++;
  }
}
```

No matter how much you increment `p` it will never be equal to `p+5`.

Comment: I see, it was so dumb of me to ask such questions. But I literally got too confused, Thanks man

Comment: @Shubharthak asking questions is never dumb. Also, not sure if it is just me, but I consider it impolite to reply to an answer along the line of "oh it was just a stupid mistake", just saying...